# Use angular-ui timepicker as input form

Tags: angularjs, input, angular-ui-bootstrap, timepicker

I'm using angular-ui timepicker according to the example [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). This is my HTML:

```
<timepicker data-ng-model="hour" data-ng-change="changed()" data-hour-step="1" data-minute-step="5" data-show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
```

In the js file, I'm trying to get the value with

```
var start_hour = {
            hour:new Date($scope.hour).getHours(),
            min:new Date($scope.hour).getMinutes()
        };
```

But it's only works if I set a new date in JS and I can't get the time inputted in the page. Want I want is to use the timepicker as a input to allow a filter based on the date but also in the time. I googled a lot for this, but I couldn't find anything

Just FIY, this is my complete HTML with datepicker where I get the date (this is works fine):

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="InitialDate">Date:</label>
        <div id="InitialDate" class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="Initial" data-datepicker-popup="yyyy/MM/dd" data-ng-model="date"
                   data-is-open="datepickers.date" data-datepicker-options="dateOptions" data-date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" data-ng-required="true"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <timepicker data-ng-model="hour" data-ng-change="changed()" data-hour-step="1" data-minute-step="5" data-show-meridian="ismeridian"></timepicker>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in this case was caused by a error in the `changed()` function.

With this function in the controller, all works fine:

```
$scope.changed = function () {
      $scope.start_hour = {
        hour: $scope.hour.getHours(),
        min: $scope.hour.getMinutes()
        };  
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$scope.$watch`: [scope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

```
$scope.$watch('hour', function(newValue) {
   $scope.start_hour = {
        hour:new Date(newValue).getHours(),
        min:new Date(newValue).getMinutes()
    };  
});
```

Every time that the hour value changes, angular will call that function and update your start_hour variable.

Comment: Thx for your help. Actually, the `changed()` function already does it. I was using this function in the wrong way.